# Minimal Loop usage on complex json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
$("<div>", {class: "wrapper"}).append(
        $("<div>", {class: "LeftSection"}).append(
            $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "MyMainSavingsTop"})).append($("<table>")),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpenses"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpensesTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "MyEverydayExpensesTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpensesBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyDeposit"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyDepositTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "MyDepositTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyDepositBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "FavDeposit"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "FavDepositTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "FavDepositTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "FavDepositBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   )
        ), 
        $("<div>", {class: "RightSection"}).append(
   $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoan"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoanTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "HomeLoanTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoanBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "Ruby"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "RubyTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "RubyTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "RubyBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraft"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraftTop"}).append($("<table>",{class: "MyOverdraftTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraftBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
            )
    )).appendTo("body")
```

I am trying to traverse through every inner element of the below complx json structure.However the for and each loop that I am using are not good enough. I need to point at a certain key, eg. MyMainSavingsTop, and get the name of that key in jquery.

```js
     var mainObject = {
     "Main": [{
      "I_Have": [{
      "typeofAcc": "casa",
      "key": "MyMainSavings",
      "MyMainSavings": {
        "MyMainSavingsTop": {
          "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
          "AccountNumber": "x726",
          "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
          "Rate": ""
        },
        "MyMainSavingsBottom": [{
          "Available": "Available",
          "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
          "Clear": "Clear",
          "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
          "Hold": "Hold",
          "Value": "$5000"
        }]
      }
        }, {
      "key": "MyEverydayExpenses",
      "MyEverydayExpenses": {
        "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
          "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
          "AccountNumber": "x726",
          "Balance": "USD 600.00",
          "Rate": ""
        },
        "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": [{
          "Available": "Available",
          "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
          "Clear": "Clear",
          "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
          "Hold": "Hold",
          "Value": "$7300"
        }]
      }
        }, {
      "key": "FavDeposit",
      "FavDeposit": {
        "FavDepositTop": {
          "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
          "AccountNumber": "x726",
          "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
          "Rate": "@4.5%"
        },
        "FavDepositBottom": [{
          "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
          "Value": "$4009"
        }, {
          "Term": "Term",
          "Value": "$1156"
        }, {
          "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
          "Value": "$5000"
        }]
      }
       }, {
      "key": "MyDeposit",
      "MyDeposit": {
        "MyDepositTop": {
          "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
          "AccountNumber": "x726",
          "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
          "Rate": "@4.5%"
        },
        "MyDepositBottom": [{
          "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
          "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
          "Term": "Term",
          "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
          "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
          "Value": "$5000"
        }]
      }
    }]
     }, {
    "I_Owe": [

      {
        "key": "HomeLoan",
        "HomeLoan": {
          "HomeLoanTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
            "Rate": "@4.5% floating"
          },
          "HomeLoanBottom": [{
            "Installment": "Installment",
            "Value": "$4329"
          }, {
            "Disbursed": "Disbursed",
            "Value": "$3456"
          }, {
            "CurrentDues": "Current Dues",
            "Value": "$5000"
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "key": "Ruby",
        "Ruby": {
          "RubyTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 600.00",
            "Rate": ""
          },
          "RubyBottom": [{
            "$6500 Dues": "$6500 Dues",
            "Value": "$4329"
          }, {
            "Minimum Due": "Minimum Due",
            "Value": "$3456"
          }, {
            "Unbilled": "Unbilled",
            "Value": "$7300"
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "key": "MyOverdraft",
        "MyOverdraft": {
          "MyOverdraftTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
            "Rate": ""
          },
          "MyOverdraftBottom": [{
            "Available": "Available",
            "Value": "$4009"
          }, {
            "Unclear": "Unclear",
            "Value": "$1156"
          }, {
            "Sanc_Limit": "Sanc. Limit",
            "Value": "$5000"
          }]
        }
      }
      ]
     }]
     }
```

I have tried the following:

```js
$.each(mainObject, function(key, v) {
      if (mainObject.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
        var val = mainObject[v];
        var table123 = $('<table></table>') //.addClass('MyMainSavingsTop');
        for (i = 0; i < this.key.length; i++) {
          var row = $('<tr></tr>').text(this.v);
          table123.append(row);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
In light of the new info I have created something for adding cells to a table based on the structure given and what was described.  More could be done but without more info about what you need its a bit difficult.  Checkout this jsfiddle for my code.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/620wkL4v/26/)

**Note**
  For using the jsfiddle in the link remove anything after appending the containers.  The JS in the jsFiddle will append it all as necessary.

Example:
`$("<div>", {class: "LeftSection"}).append(
  $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}),
  $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpenses"})
)`

***Below is just for reference and may be useful to someone***

A recursive approach would probably be nice

```js
function getSubItems(obj, key, wrap) {
  var result;
  var arr;
  switch (obj.constructor.name) {
    case "Object":
      arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
        if (k == key)
          return {
            __wrapper: obj[k]
          };
        return getSubItems(obj[k], key, true);
      });
      break;
    case "Array":
      arr = obj.map(function(i) {
        return getSubItems(i, key, true)
      })
      break;
  }

  if (arr)
    if (arr.length > 0)
      result = arr
      .filter(function(item) {
        if (item)
          if (item.constructor)
            return item.constructor.name === "Object";
      })[0]
  if (result)
    if (result.__wrapper && wrap === undefined)
      return result.__wrapper
  return result;
}
```

The above code takes an object (or array) and parses it to find the object with the Key specified.  This code makes the assumption that there is only 1 key of that name that exists in the object.  To use this function run the following:

`getSubItem(myMainObj, "KeyToSearchFor")`